# Efficient Oracle PLSQL stored procedure to return sys_refcursor for similar, but different, SQL statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

Am writing a PL/SQL stored procedure which needs to return a `sys_refcursor` containing JSON derived from a single table.

The SQL will have a consistent `SELECT` clause, but 2 different `WHERE` clauses, depending on inputs, and optional offset and fetch next statements.

While I have a brute force implementation, it feels very inefficient with a lot of duplicated code split between 6 IF statements.

Here's a stylized version of this brute force approach:

```
procedure query_my_table
(
     in_param_1
     ...
     in_param_n
     ...
    in_limit           number,
    in_offset          number,
    ref            out sys_refcursor
) is
begin
    if in_param_n is null then
        if nvl(in_offset, 0) = 0 then
            open ref for
            select json_object( ... cols ...
                    format json) as json
               from my_table
              where col_1 = in_param_1 and col_2 = in_param_2 and col_3 = in_param_3
        elsif nvl(in_limit, 0) = 0 then
            open ref for
            select json_object( ... cols ...
                    format json) as json
               from my_table
              where col_1 = in_param_1 and col_2 = in_param_2 and col_3 = in_param_3
            offset in_offset rows;
        else
            open ref for
            select json_object( ... cols ...
                    format json) as json
               from my_table
              where col_1 = in_param_1 and col_2 = in_param_2 and col_3 = in_param_3
            offset in_offset rows
            fetch next in_limit rows only;
        end if;
    else
        if nvl(in_offset, 0) = 0 then
            open ref for
            select json_object( ... cols ...
                    format json) as json
               from my_table
              where col_n=in_param_n;
        elsif nvl(in_limit, 0) = 0 then
            open ref for
            select json_object( ... cols ...
                    format json) as json
               from my_table
              where col_n=in_param_n
             offset in_offset rows;
        else
            open ref for
            select json_object( ... cols ...
                    format json) as json
               from my_table
              where col_n=in_param_n
             offset in_offset rows;
            offset in_offset rows
            fetch next in_limit rows only;
        end if;
    end if;
exception
    when others then
        if ref%isopen then
            close ref;
        end if;
        -- handle exception
end query_my_table;
```

Since the only thing that varies is the `WHERE` clause (including the fetch/offset), I hope it can be written more efficiently.

I have tried building dynamic SQL, but it fails compilation - the pattern I used was:

```
the_sql := <string with SELECT statement>;
open ref for
   execute immediate the_sql;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: See [Native dynamic sql - Refcursor](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1443111916680)

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite it as:

```sql
PROCEDURE query_my_table
(
  in_param_1
  ...
  in_param_n
  in_limit  IN  number,
  in_offset IN  number,
  ref       OUT sys_refcursor
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR
    SELECT json
    FROM   (
      SELECT json_object(
               ... cols ...
               format json
             ) as json,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) AS rn
      FROM   my_table
      WHERE  col_1 = in_param_1
      AND    col_2 = in_param_2
      AND    col_3 = in_param_3
      AND    (col_n = in_param_n OR in_param_n IS NULL)
    )
    WHERE (in_offset IS NULL OR in_offset < rn)
    AND   (in_limit  IS NULL OR rn <= in_limit + COALESCE(in_offset, 0));
END query_my_table;
```

Comment: It's worth to notice that Oracle internally uses `row_number()/dense_rank()` for `offset X rows fetch next Y rows { only | with ties}`, so this code is a more explicit version of this functionality

Comment: @MT0 This is really helpful - thank you! I had gone down the path of thinking I had to use `offset/fetch next`.

Comment: @astentx That's good to know. One follow up is that I was wondering of the impact of the `ORDER BY` - since for the specific case I'm working on, order is not significant I used the primary key column, but am curious what the impact of a big dataset might be.

Comment: @AlanPollard In SQL (not just Oracle SQL) the order of result sets is non-deterministic if you do not `ORDER BY` something; therefore if you do not order the rows and you want to get rows 1-10 in one execution and 11-20 in the next execution then there is no guarantee that that you will not get the same row in both executions as the result set may be fetched in a different order each time. You may say that the `ORDER BY` is irrelevant but I think you will find that it is necessary for reliable pagination. If it really is irrelevant then use `ROWNUM as rn` rather than using `ROW_NUMBER() ...`.

Comment: @AlanPollard You may use `order by null` which will result in `window nosort stopkey` plan operator, that actually doesn't sort anything. It's suitable to fetch arbitrary sample of data